# Creating Checkbox functionality using Bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have built a great set of bootstrap icons that act like radio buttons. I need to do the same thing bug with checkbox behavior allowing multiple options to be selected and stored. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it.

HTML

```
<h1>AUTOMATIC TASKS
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked user-dems">
    <li ng-repeat="optionText in type.options" class="underline"><a href="#" ng-click="selectType(optionText)" class="queue-type queue-text-margin"><span ng-class="{&quot;glyphicon-ok&quot;:type.selected===optionText,&quot;glyphicon-unchecked&quot;:type.selected!==optionText}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok queue-box-padding"></span>{{optionText}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</h1>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvQueueListCtrl', function($scope, mvQueue) {

 ........
 ........

  $scope.selectType = function(opt){
      $scope.type.selected = opt

  },


  $scope.type = {
      options: ['Fax', 'Physical', 'Digital'],
      //selected: 'None'
      selected: 'Fax'
    },


 ..........
 ..........
 ..........

}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your view model a bit to indicate it it has been selected or not, so instead of array of primitives change it to array of objects:-

```
$scope.type = {
   options: [{name:'Fax', selected:true},
         {name:'Physical', selected:false}, 
         {name:'Digital', selected:false}],
};
```

And update your handler to toggle the check mark.

```
 $scope.selectType = function(opt){
      opt.selected = !opt.selected;
  };
```

Just change your `ng-repeat`  a bit.

- Pass option on click `ng-click="selectType(option)"`
- Simplify `ng-class` to `ng-class="{'true' : 'glyphicon-ok', false:'glyphicon-unchecked'}[option.selected]"`

---

```
<li ng-repeat="option in type.options track by $index">
      <a href="#" ng-click="selectType(option)" class="queue-type queue-text-margin">
        <span ng-class="{'true' : 'glyphicon-ok', false:'glyphicon-unchecked'}[option.selected]" 
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok queue-box-padding"></span>{{option.name}}
      </a>
</li>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6mB1ONENOhC6V99sd8ow?p=preview)**